# csv file to date format

Tags: python, date, csv

I would like to read in a csv file of dates (shown below) and loop through it using solar.GetAltitude on each date to calculate a list of sun altitudes.  (I'm using Python 2.7.2 on Windows 7 Enterprise.)

```
CSV file: TimeStamp 01/01/2014 00:10 01/01/2014 00:20 01/01/2014 00:30
01/01/2014 00:40
```

My code gives the following error `ValueError: unconverted data remains:`.  This suggests the wrong date format, but it works fine on a single date, rather than a string of dates.

I've researched this topic carefully on Stack Overflow.  I've also tried the map function, `np.datetime64` and reading to a list rather than a string but get a different error referring to `no attribute 'year'`.

I'd really appreciate any help because I'm running out of ideas.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import julian
import solar
from solar import *
import os
import csv

# Create lists to hold the records.
dates = []

# Navigate to correct directory
os.chdir('D:\\Di_Python')

filename = 'SPA timestamp small.csv'

# Read through the entire file, skip the first line
with open(filename) as f:
    # Create a csv reader object.
   reader = csv.reader(f)

# Ignore the header row.
   next(reader)

# Store the dates in the appropriate list.
   for row in reader:
      dates.append(row)
      print row

    # Change list to string so can use a function on it
   lines = []
   for date in dates:
      lines.append('\t'.join(map(str, date)))
      result = '\n'.join(lines)
      print result

   minutes = []
   minutes.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(result,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))

# Inputs
latitude_deg = 52.8
longitude_deg = -1.2
elevation = 0

# i should be 52560 - 10 min interval whole year
for i in minutes:
        utc_datetime = i
        altitude = solar.GetAltitude(latitude_deg, longitude_deg, utc_datetime)
        altitude_list.append(altitude)
        print altitude_list
```

Comment: Please include a longer sample of the CSV file. And please tell us which line of your code gives the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the code is not indented properly making it harder to guess.

I think the input to `datetime.datetime.strptime` is not correct. You create `result` by using a `'\n'.join(...)` but the format string does not contain the `'\n'`. Creating a string from the list of dates seems unnecessary to me.

I think what you want is this:

```
for date in dates:
    minutes.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
```

Note that the names you use for the lists are misleading as `minutes` holds `datetime.datetime` objects rather than minute values!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Vikramis and Lutz Horn for their help and comments.  After experimenting with Vikramis' code, I achieved a working version which I have copied below.

My error occurred at line 40:

```
minutes.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(result,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
```

I found that I needed to create a string from the list to avoid the following error "TypeError: must be string, not list".  I have now tidied this up by using (str(date) to replace the for loop and hopefully used more sensible names.

My problem was with the formatting.  It needs to be 
**"['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M']"** because I'm accessing items in a list, rather than **"'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'"** which works in the shell for a single date.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import julian
import solar
from solar import *
import os
import csv

# Create lists to hold the records.
dates = []
datetimeObj = []
altitude_list = []

# Navigate to correct directory
os.chdir('D:\\Di_Python')

filename = 'SPA timestamp small.csv'

# Read through the entire file, skip the first line
with open(filename) as f:
    # Create a csv reader object.
    reader = csv.reader(f)

# Ignore the header row.
    next(reader)

# Store the dates in the appropriate list.
    for row in reader:
        dates.append(row)
        print row     

    # Change format to datetime
    # str(date) used to avoid TypeError: must be string, not list
    for date in dates:
        datetimeObj.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date),"['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M']"))

    for j in datetimeObj:
        print j

# Inputs
latitude_deg = 52.8
longitude_deg = -1.2
elevation = 0

# i should be 52560 - 10 min interval whole year
for i in datetimeObj:
        utc_datetime = i
        altitude = solar.GetAltitude(latitude_deg, longitude_deg, utc_datetime)
        print altitude
        altitude_list.append(altitude)
# print altitude_list
```